# Keep the text inside each facet window with gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate

I want the label of my facets to be inside the plot so I used geom_text(). The plot is fine but when I added `transition_reveal(Year)` I get the following error:
Error: `along data must be the same class in all layers`. I remove the geom_text and it works fine. Is there a way to make it work and add the text inside each panel?

Plot

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(colour=Element, x=Year,y=Value))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Element~.,scales = "free_y")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1975,2015, by=5),2019))+
  geom_text(data = df_text,aes(label=lab,y=value2),colour="black",vjust="right",hjust="left")+
  scale_colour_jco()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
      panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid",fill = NA),
      axis.text.y=element_text(size=13,margin=margin(5,8,5,5,"pt"), colour = "black"),
      axis.text.x= element_text(size=13,margin=margin(5,5,5,5,"pt"), colour = "black"),
      axis.title =element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.15, "cm"),
      strip.text = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "none")
```

Data

```
df<-structure(list(Year = c(1975L, 1978L, 1980L, 1985L, 1988L, 1990L, 
1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 1975L, 1978L, 1980L, 1985L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L
), Value = c(29.07, 38.43, 48.65, 82.28, 142.87, 180.77, 205.65, 
261.35, 371.9, 510.81, 631.45, 713.6, 802.59, 901.19, 1018.97, 
1191.25, 1368.55, 1583.51, 1869.4, 2270.16, 2687.46, 3183.18, 
3750.16, 4401.56, 4853.87, 5749.02, 6725.76, 7424.32, 8147.32, 
8850.54, 9472.4, 10193.29, 11037.28, 12001.52, 5742206, 5853321, 
5961129, 6267223, 6516920, 6571597, 6666482, 6709277, 6731072, 
6753497, 6785291, 6846346, 6902677, 6954391, 6995666, 7029707, 
7066481, 7104850, 7156537, 7206806, 7311228, 8195500, 8294200, 
8386700, 8456100, 8500300, 8715100, 8868500, 8868500, 8964100, 
9046200, 9097000, 9204000, 9290500, 9394800), Element = c("GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", 
"Population", "Population", "Population")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-69L))
```

Text data

```
df_text<-structure(list(Year = c(1975, 1975), value2 = c(8455320, 10801.368
), Value = c(9e+06, 11000), Element = c("Population", "GDP"), 
    lab = c("Population (Persons)", "Gross Primary Product (100 million RMB)"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

The plot I want to animate:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a subtle difference between the `Year` column in your two data frames. `df$Year` is of class `integer` whereas `df_text$Year` is of class `numeric`.

So if you do

```r
df_text$Year <- as.integer(df_text$Year)
```

Then run your plotting code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(ggsci)

ggplot(data = df, aes(colour = Element, x = Year, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Element~., scales = "free_y")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1975, 2015, by = 5), 2019)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  geom_text(data = df_text, aes(label = lab, y = value2), 
            colour = "black", vjust = "right", hjust = "left") +
  scale_colour_jco() +
  theme(panel.background  = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.border      = element_rect(linetype = "solid", fill = NA),
        axis.text.y       = element_text(size   = 13, 
                                         margin = margin(5, 8, 5, 5, "pt"), 
                                         colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x       = element_text(size   = 13,
                                         margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5, "pt"), 
                                         colour = "black"),
        axis.title        = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.15, "cm"),
        strip.text        = element_blank(),
        legend.position   = "none") +
  transition_reveal(Year)
```

You will get:

[image]